# Why I can see class/struct names in .exe file compiled using Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, obfuscation, exe, reverse-engineering

When looking at a compiled **relese .exe file binary** I can find class/struct names in it! Which is odd - obviously there is no need in these symbols. What concerns me is such symbols can be used for reverse-engeniging my software, imposing a big risk to software license protection.

For example, I can find text .?AVCMySecureKeyManager (original class name is CMySecureKeyManager, it looks like to all names is added prefix ".?AV"), easy to guess what my code is doing, right?.. Looks like an open door for hackers.

Particularly, I can tell that I've **enabled all possible optimizations** the Visual C++ compiler/linker options, **turned off all Browse/Debug Info generation**, perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: It's just class name right? how is exposing just class names is a big risk?

Comment: Worried? Look at SoftICE! Hackers will hack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing [RTTI](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/23) (Run-time Type Information). If you don't use `dynamic_cast` or `typeid` in your code, you can usually turn it off safely. Please note that exceptions always use RTTI (for the `catch` statement matching) and it's not possible to disable it for them.

If you do need `dynamic_cast`, then you can scrub the names from the EXE after compilation. The code does not depend on the actual name strings, but just their addresses.

That said, the class names, while useful, are not critical in reverse-engineering. Don't rely on their absence as a guarantee.

Comment: Perfect! Disabling the /GR- compiler option did the trick!!! Thank you! And my .exe got 55Kb smaller in size :)